# whats happening to the interface?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made a little code to plot some data from a file

```
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import *

with open("specfunc_from_idft_U8p0g_gate-1p5U.txt") as f:
    data = f.read()

data = data.split('\n')

x = [row.split(' ')[0] for row in data]
y = [row.split(' ')[1] for row in data]

fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax1.set_title("Reference plot")
ax1.set_xlabel('$\\omega/U$')
ax1.set_ylabel('$A(\\omega)$')

ax1.plot(x,y, c='r', label='$NRG$')

leg = ax1.legend()

plt.savefig('varying_alpha_hf_withJ_'+str('ff'+'.png'))
```

File [specfunc_from_idft_U8p0g_gate-1p5U.txt](https://pastebin.com/nBA20FDh)

When I open the saved file this is what I get

[image]

What I have to do to repair the machine? I am using Python 3.7 in a Mac os X

Comment: You need to post the plot code otherwise it's very hard to tell what the problem is.

Comment: Does this happen again if you rerun the code?

Comment: @jingx means the code and the data the created this output Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Megalng yes, it doesn't matter if a show or save the plot, the same happens

Comment: The image has the result. I'm taking about the python code you wrote to plot that.

Comment: We also need the content of `specfunc_from_idft_U8p0g_gate-1p5U.txt` (or at least enough of it to reproduce this issue).

Comment: @jingx I have included it, but it happens with other plots differents from this. Thanks in advance

Comment: That is not enough data to reproduce anything. Post the whole file [here](https://pastebin.com/) and share the link.

Comment: @MegaIng done. Thank you for your patience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at your data and your program, it turns out you only have problems loading the data for two reasons

```
x = [row.split(' ')[0] for row in data]
y = [row.split(' ')[1] for row in data]
```

If you look at this code, you can see that `x` and `y` are going to be list of strings which is not what you want. That they are strings is the reason for the overlapping `xticks` and `yticks`. You want them all to be floats:

```
x = [float(row.split(' ')[0]) for row in data]
y = [float(row.split(' ')[1]) for row in data]
```

Doing this reveals the main flaw with the loading:

```
    x = [float(row.split(' ')[0]) for row in data]
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

If you look at the file you will see that after line 250 the lines begin with a space which breaks the `split` function to a small degree:

```
>>> " 0.000000000E+00 0.240699776E+02 0.200482966E+01 0.495502884E-16 0.153587396E+01 0.000000000E+00".split(" ")
['', '0.000000000E+00', '0.240699776E+02', '0.200482966E+01', '0.495502884E-16', '0.153587396E+01', '0.000000000E+00']
```

As you can see the first element is empty, which can't be a number. So instead of `.split(" ")` you should use `.split()`, which will deal with spaces at the beggining:

```
>>> " 0.000000000E+00 0.240699776E+02 0.200482966E+01 0.495502884E-16 0.153587396E+01 0.000000000E+00".split()
['0.000000000E+00', '0.240699776E+02', '0.200482966E+01', '0.495502884E-16', '0.153587396E+01', '0.000000000E+00']
```

So here is the working loading code:

```
x = [float(row.split()[0]) for row in data]
y = [float(row.split()[1]) for row in data]
```

Comment: You are completely right! thank you very much for your time